# How to convert an integer to a Knuth notation?

Tags: notation, big-numbers

The Knuth notation enables to write very large number in a compact way.

I however cannot find the way to do the reverse calculation.For instance, given the number $123456789$ , how can it be written in the Knuth notation?

The only way in I could think about is to range it using preknown numbers in Knuth notation.

Comment: Do you mean using the arrow notation or...?

Comment: You can always write $123456789 = 123456789^1 = 123456789\uparrow 1$ and you've expressed it in Knuth notation. If you want to disregard this trivial solution, then you can't expect a general number to be expressible as a single term of the form $a\uparrow\cdots\uparrow b$, so I'm assuming you mean something like expressing $123456789$ as a sum of such terms. There will be many ways to do so. Maybe you have other constraints in mind that would make the representation unique.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  You seem to be interested in compressing numbers.  Unfortunately, "There is a corresponding trade-off between preserving information and reducing size" as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Lossy  and this is generally true of all compression.  So while you can compress some numbers in Knuth notation, there will inevitably be some numbers that you cannot compress (in the total size of the formula)

Comment: Even $$a \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow b$$ with $a,b\ge 3$ is larger than any number you will want to express. With $a=b=3$ , we have $3^{27}$ threes in the power tower. So, best is to use powers (but even this will usualy not give an exact representation, unless you allow $n^1$) or perhaps tetration.

Comment: But even tetration soon transcendents the numbers we usually have to deal with. Knuth's up-arrow notation is designed for REALLY large numbers and moreover is quite limited since even in the case of tetration , the entries in the power tower must be equal. So, at the end , it is best to approximate the number with a power (usually even this will not give an exact result, unless the exponent can be $1$)